# How do I select all content between two points in the viewport with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to find a way to select all content between two points in the view port.  I need that selection to cross HTML elements as well.

Consider a page with two moveable boxes.  These boxes are moved by the user around the content.  They are absolutely positioned on the screen in front of all the content.  When the boxes are moved, I need to select all content in between them.  Has anybody come across anything similar?  What I'm essentially trying to do is mimic smart phone selection handles.

I know there is a javascript function document.elementFromPoint(x, y).  That won't work in this case because the boxes will be selected as the top most elements at the point.

Comment: Specifically the android os web view.  Fortunately I have a very limited and specific range of targets.

Comment: Oh well, that's two thirds of my answer that won't be helpful to you then :)

Comment: Sorry about that Tim, but your answer looks perfect. We will be implementing over the next couple of days to see if it works.

Comment: Not a problem at all. How did it go?

Comment: Not bad.  Still having some issues, but they're android related not javascript.  Also, word is you're responsible for the Rangy library.  We're using that too, and it's a life saver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WebKit and Opera, you could do this as follows:

- Get the coordinates of your drag handles
- Hide the drag handles
- Call [`document.caretPositionFromPoint(dragHandleX, dragHandleY)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-document-caretpositionfrompoint) on each drag handle
- Create a new range from the two caret positions (each consisting of a node and an offset within that node) obtained in the previous step
- Select this range
- Unhide your drag handles

In Firefox, mouse events have `rangeParent` and `rangeOffset` properties that may help, though I think you'd need to somehow hide the the drag handles before the event fires.

In IE, you could do something like this:

- Get the coordinates of your drag handles
- Hide the drag handles
- Create a TextRange for each drag handle using `document.body.createTextRange()`
- Call [`moveToPoint(dragHandleX, dragHandleY)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on each TextRange
- Extend the first TextRange to end at the second TextRange using [`setEndPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `firstTextRange.setEndPoint(secondTextRange)`
- Select this range: `firstTextRange.select()`
- Unhide your drag handles

Answer (score 0):

```
var leftBound = Math.min(point1.x, point2.x);
var rightBound = Math.max(point1.x, point2.x);
var topBound = Math.min(point1.y, point2.y);
var bottomBound = Math.max(point1.y, point2.y);

$(".").filter(function(x) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var top=offset.top, bottom=top+$(this).height;
    var left=offset.left, right=left+$(this).width;
    var corners = [[left,top], [left,bottom], [right,top], [right,bottom]];

    function inBox(point) {
        var x=point[0], y=point[1];
        return (leftBound<=x && x<=rightBound) && (topBound<=y && y<=bottomBound)
    }

    // overlap-based selection policy
    //   selects if one or more corners is in selection
    return corners.some(inBox);

    // overlap-based selection policy #2
    //   selects if any part of element is in selection
    return corners.some(inBox) //|| ... slightly more complicated logic

    // only-wholly-enclosed selection policy
    //   selects only if entire element is in selection
    return corners.every(inBox);
})
```

Replace `$(".")` with your favorite method of recursive callback-based DOM traversal if you don't want jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it it might be better to keep track of element positions yourself and calculate which element would be touched from within your javascript code. This will reduce your interaction with the DOM.

If not the only method I've heard of or used for getting elements from behind others is detailed here:
http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

It essentially involves hiding the element that receives the original element momentarily, then using elementFromPoint() to find the element below. In your case you could perform this between your two boxes and repeat until you hit your containing element. This might be too resource intense if you've got a large area and a large number of elements.

I've only used it in a situation where I wanted to hide the top element anyway, but you could test it to see if there are visible display distortions or not.